# Jquery issue with getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My issue is a javascript issue, i try to parse a Json file with the $.getJson function of Jquery and when i put them each in a variable, i noted that it takes more objects that i thought, here the code JS:

```
$.getJSON(
url,
function(data) {
   var content = '<h1>Applications</h1>';
   content += '<ul>';
       for (var pos in data){
           var app = data[pos];
           content += '<li>'+app.name+'</li>';
       }
   content += '</ul>';
   $('div.apps').html(content);
}
```

and here the json file:

```
[
 {
    "name": "apidocs",
    "staging": {
        "model": "rack",
        "stack": "ruby18"
 }
 ,
 {
    "name": "apidocs2",
    "staging": {
        "model": "rack",
        "stack": "php53"
 }
 ,
 {
    "name": "apidocs3",
    "staging": {
        "model": "rack",
        "stack": "java17"
 }
]
```

So then, in my html page i have in globality 6 objects instead of 3. the 3 last are as "undefined" but i would like only those which are in the json file because firefox don't accept the undefined tags.

Comment: The JSON is not valid. Missing `}` for `staging`.

Comment: If it isn't because of the invalid JSON, my guess would be that it might have something to do with the `for (var pos in data)` line. There might be something the prototype of `data` that this is iterating through as well?

Comment: try logging it to the console.. it always helps `console.log(data)` in chrome's build-in developper tools or set a breakpoint and debug.. you 'll find your issue in a jiffy! Like mentioned in the answers.. Avoid using for..in.. for arrays for example it adds the length param.. usually not what you where going for

Answer (score 0):

```
       for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
           var app = data[ i ];
           content += '<li>'+app.name+'</li>';
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

**AVOID** `for..in` loops.

```
for (var pos in data){
```

replace it with the usual:

```
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){ //use as data[i]
```

If you are using for..in loop, be sure to use `data.hasOwnProperty(..)` before using it. Otherwise, you are bound to get more objects than you expect. They are actually other attributes that the `data` inherits.

Comment: ok it works like this, thanks again and i will be prudent with the for..in, don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

Correct the JSON, you have too many opening tags.

**[Corrected JSON>>](http://jsfiddle.net/apna3/)**

Additionaly, correct the for loop. Use `var count = 0; count < data.length; count++`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, use its perfect `$.each` function.

```
$.each( data, function( d ) {
    content += '<li>' + d.name + '</li>';
});
```